# Question about a for looping in some exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sup guys,
I'm new to this world and I started learning JS about 3 weeks ago. I'm stuck in some exercise about finding a result inside a looping with an array(sorry if didn't made myself clear enough).

the this is:

I want to set an array["a","b"...] and I want to make letter a or b to be marked in order to run a looping and if doesn't return like ["b", "b", "b"] = false. if return true.

I've being doing by myself and this is what I get

```
function isUniform(letras) {
    let b = letras[1];
    for(let i = 0; i <= letras.lenght; i++){
        if(letras[i] !== b){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

if I try to run this code will always get a true. I know I'm doing something wrong still can't find the error.

Can someone enlighten me?

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: actually javascript provies `Array.every()` for this task. `letras.every(letter => letter === "b")`

Comment: is this case I cannot use anything besides a for looping since the exercise is about arrays functions and for loop. but thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change letras.lenght for letras.length

```js
for(let i = 0; i <= letras.length; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks for seeing this and helping me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: With this change (only), the function always returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Last part of your question is not very clear still I'll try to answer from what i got, you are basically trying to implement a search algorithm which will check for repeated occurrence of a letter in an array.

Here is what will help,
-Remove the var b
-use if letras[i]!=letras[i+1]
If the above doesn't work try with .toString() after square bracs